# How many view controllers is too many view controllers?

Tags: ios, performance, uistoryboard

I'm creating a reference app for a game showing everything the user needs to know in order to be good at the game. Weapons, maps, random information, etc.

I am 1/10 of the way done and I already have over 45 views controllers in my storyboard. I only have one storyboard since I don't know how to create another one and link it to the first storyboard. The storyboard is starting to lag a little bit. How many views is too many views?

Once I'm done, I'm guessing I'll have over 100 view controllers in one storyboard. Is that too many? If yes, is there a simple way to fix that problem?

(I have so many views controllers because I created one for every individual item.)

I would create 5 storyboards (one for every category in the main menu) to see if it would reduce the lag, but I don't want to do that if it's not going to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can create multiple storyboards in one application and Apple do not stops you from doing that. It is highly recommend to divide your app screens into modules and put those modules into different storyboards and navigate between them flawlessly.

You can have a look at this library for integrating multiple stroyboards in your application:

https://github.com/rob-brown/RBStoryboardLink